# Guaranteed success after $x$ tries?

Tags: probability

Not sure if there is already a question on this, but if there is, I can't find it due to a combination of my first language (and thus language of studying math) being Finnish, not English, and not having refreshed my memory on math terminology in a couple of years, so here's a new one.

Now, I am not a math guy by any means, so I have to ask the good folks here for some help.

In relation to a certain game, another person was telling me, that repeating an action with a $20\%$ chance of success would eventually result in a guaranteed success. This sounded off to me, since shouldn't it be a chance of $1-0.8^n$? As far as I remember, this should never result in an actual $100\%$ guarantee, right?

(The other person was being completely serious about it eventually being absolutely $100\%$ guaranteed. For reference, there is no mechanic put in place in the game to specifically give a success after $x$ tries. The action can also be only repeated up to $100$ times at once, but that limit was not relevant to this discussion.)

Comment: You are totally right. There is no mathematical guarantee of success after any $n$ steps.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: You may however find a number of attempts to guarantee that the probability of at least one success is at least $100\%-\epsilon$ for any value of $\epsilon>0$.  That is to say, we can find an $n$ to make it at least $90\%$ to have at least one success just as we can find an $n$ to make it at least $99.99999\%$ chance success, etc...

Comment: This is an excellent example of the difference between "certain" (always happens) and "almost certain" (happens with probability 1).